# Align the author names in Handout of Beamer by Tabular environment

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

Consider the following framework:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}

\title[]{Title}
\author[]{
 Author 1: "name of author 1"\\
 Author 2: "name of author 2"}
 \institute[]{}
 \date[]{}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}


 \end{document}
```

The problem is I would like to align the author names such that the two colon marks lie on the same line. I have tried this:

```
 \author{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
 Author 1:& "name of author 1" \tabularnewline
 Author 2:& "name of author 2"
 \end{tabular}}
```

which I know by asking another question here and which works exactly as I want in the Article documentclass. However, it does not work in Handout of Beamer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply put it inside the `document` and not in the preamble and it will work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}


\begin{document}

\title[]{Title}
 \author{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
 Author 1:& "name of author 1" \tabularnewline
 Author 2:& "name of author 2"
 \end{tabular}}
 \institute[]{}
 \date[]{}

 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to keep that code in the preamble, you can use `\AtBeginDocument` in this way

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\title[]{Title}
 \author{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
 Author 1:& "name of author 1" \tabularnewline
 Author 2:& "name of author 2"
 \end{tabular}}
 \institute[]{}
 \date[]{}
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```